# Growth bound on conformal map

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Hello all,

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the upper half plane, and $i+\mathbb{H}$ be all points with imaginary 
part greater than 1. Suppose that $U$ is a domain with a nice boundary 
and with $i+\mathbb{H} \subseteq U \subseteq \mathbb{H}$. Let $f(z)$ be the conformal 
map from $\mathbb{H}$ to $U$ which fixes $2i$, which extends continuously to the real 
axis, and which maps $0$ to a point on the intersection of the imaginary axis and the 
boundary of $U$. I would like to show that there is a constant $K$ such 
that

$|f(z)| < K(1+|z|) $

for all $z \in \mathbb{H}$. I think that this is true because it is true if $U = i+\mathbb{H}$(so $f(z) = i+ z/2$) and if $U=\mathbb{H}$(so $f(z)=z$), so I am hoping that there is some kind of "pinch" theorem which works here, but I don't see how to get at this. 
If it helps, we can also assume that the boundary of $U$ gets 
arbitrarily close to the real axis near infinity, or even that it is 
something nice like the graph of $y=1/(1+x^2)$ if that helps. I hope 
that there is some kind of general theory that someone can point me 
to. Thanks.

Greg

Answer (score 1):

In general it should be wrong. Your map is uniquely determined and there is no reason why infinity should go to infinity (in general it would not). This means that there is a point $x$ on the boundary which is mapped to infinity. At this point your inequality is wrong.

Comment: Hmm, ok, you're right, and thanks for your answer. But let's look at the case determined by $y=1/(1+x^2)$. The map is, as you say, uniquely determined, and thus by symmetry we must have infinity going to infinity. Can we get a bound in this case? Actually even better would be $|f(z)/z|$ -> $1$ as $|z|$ -> $\infty$, or at least that the quotient is bounded away from 0 and $\infty$.